# Make curl not that that @something is not a file but a string

Tags: curl

I have a strange situation where the API vendor wants me to send a string starting with an ampersand:

```
curl myurl.com -x -F FOO=@vendor_required_tag;    # starting with an ampersand

curl myurl.com -x -F FOO="@vendor_required_tag";    # starting with an ampersand
```

Neither of these work and `man curl` doesn't say anything about it.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

OK I found this in the documentation:

> To send a field value literally without interpreting a leading @ or <, or an embedded ;type=, use --form-string instead of -F. This is recommended when the value is obtained from a user or some other unpredictable source. Under these circumstances, using -F instead of --form-string could allow a user to trick curl into uploading a file.

https://curl.se/docs/manual.html

so you CAN'T do this, you need to use `--form` and urlencoding as needed.  Fair enough